# Good exercices to understand vector, principal and associated bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

I'm a new stuent of differential topology and in my course I came across bundles and I'm looking now for good exercices (books, links) to understand them well !

the 3 subjects that I need to really understand are :

- Vector bundles (I know that Lee's book covers them but I still need similar exercices )
- Principal bundles
- Associated bundles

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated !

Comment: You could definitely check out Milnor and Stasheff's "Characteristic Classes"

Comment: Thank you for your syggestion !